# How to make iOS chat instant (real time)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, chat

a part of my app involves building a IM group chat. As right now, I have the whole chat working. However, the problem is that obviously is not instant. It updates in ViewDidLoad(). I know that making it instant is the hardest part in making an IM chat. I'm currently using Parse, and I initially thought of using push notifications to update the page, but Googling a little more I found out that people were saying that there are a few cons in doing that such as the fact that the user would get a crazy number of push notifications. 
Do you have any idea of how could I approach this problem or how I could get my chat to be in real time?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You have to keep a socket connection alive to pass message constantly. If you want to save time, you can pick up a third party which provide the IM SDK to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party services like PubNub (https://www.pubnub.com/) and Pusher (https://pusher.com/) that offer realtime events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know where should I start if I wanted to build a realtime chat myself?

Comment: If you're building the architecture yourself, I think you should start learning Web Sockets, which is the underlying technology behind those services.